# How to upgrade stock email client that came with CyanogenMod 6 Froyo?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 2.2-froyo, stock-email-app

For reasons beyond my control, I need to stick with the original stock email client that came with my CyanogenMod 6 phone (Froyo).

(by "stick with" I mean only the so called "package name", not that particular version)

I know that there are superior email clients out there on Google Play, but all I want at this point is to stick with the same client and only update it to a later version.

My problem is... I can't find it anywhere on Google Play as it doesn't have any distinct name other than the generic "Email" and [this icon](http://forum.vodafone.co.uk/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/4522i42EED295EA79DB79/image-size/original?v=mpbl-1&px=-1).

Is there a way to identify this app and find it on Google Play (or other Android markets)?

Comment: Pretty sure it's not distributed on Google Play.

Comment: I think @eldarerathis is right. Unless you find a website that lets you download various versions of that Email app, your best bet is to find another phone with the version that you want, attach `adb` via USB and copy that APK over.